# Transactionscope

Tags: nhibernate, transactions

Where can I reference TransactionScope? What is it used for?  Where can I have information related to that?

Can it be used to solve nested transactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ayende Rahien has also discussed this on his [blog](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/12/28/nh-prof-alerts-use-of-implicit-transactions-is-discouraged.aspx)

Regarding nested transactions read this [S.O. post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192111/how-do-i-do-nested-transactions-in-nhibernate) which actually gives you quite a bit of info. Also see this other [S.O post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646318/nhibernate-with-transactionscope)

**edit** You can also do a search on the [nhusers group](http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/search?group=nhusers&q=TransactionScope+&qt_g=Search+this+group) as this provides quite a bit of info how people use the transactionscope. Also read this [post](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/08/16/how-to-using-the-n-stack-part-4.aspx) as it provides more info