# Shouldn't nHibernate ISession.BeginTransaction() fail when a transaction is already open?

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate

I know these kinds of questions can lead to flame wars. Personally I'm a huge fan of nHibernate and I realize no ORM is perfect. I'm just trying to determine if there's a good reason for this I'm unaware of or if it's a design flaw that exists because changing it would break existing code.

Here's the behavior I'm describing:

Assuming I have an existing `ISession` named `session` shouldn't the following code throw an exception on the third line due to the fact that nHibernate does not support nested transactions.

```
ITransaction tx = null;
tx = session.BeginTransaction();
tx = session.BeginTransaction();
```

If we assume that there are no other transactions open on the current thread the first call to `BeginTransaction()` does indeed begin a transaction. However the *second* merely returns the existing transaction. It *gives the impression* that nested transactions are supported. Is this bad nomenclature?

Would it make more sense to create two methods? One for grabbing an existing transaction *or* creating one if none exists in situations where the developer doesn't care and another method that *specifically* creates new transactions and fails when it cannot?

This question is about nHibernate but perhaps this applies to Hibernate as well.

Answer (score 1):

The post [How do I do nested transactions in NHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192111/how-do-i-do-nested-transactions-in-nhibernate) contains a link to http://rajputyh.blogspot.com/2011/02/nested-transaction-handling-with.html, which provides code to deal with this situation.  (Disclaimer:  I have not tried the code, but had come across it previously when researching a different issue.)